# Почему вспомогательный метод не работает с полями ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Привет всем. Подскажите пожалуйста есть модель

```
public class Class1
    {
        //public string Test = "Blablabla";
        public string Test { get { return "Balalal"; } }
    }
```

Есть вью

```
@model MvcApplication8.Models.Class1
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>

       @Html.Display("Test")<br />

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

И контрол

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(new Class1());
        }

    }
```

Вопрос в том, почему если используется поле а не свойство, то ничего не работает (пустой экран), если наоборот, тогда все нормально ?? Можно конечно использовать строготипизированные вспомогательные методы с лямбдой, и тогда все ок. Но не могу понять почему при использовании таким образом поля ничего не работает. 
Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model binding исключает поля классов, должны быть свойства
Вместо просмотра пустого экрана - посмотрите в логи )

Comment: Спасибо, а почему тогда при использовании лямбды работает ?

Comment: Потому что используется другой механизм связывания.

Comment: т.е. типа так? @Html.Display(m => m.Test)? должно быть потому, что при использовании лямбды ожидается метод, который вернёт значение, что лямбда и делает. PS: все проперти, как и лямбды, практически являются функциями, возвращающими значения

Comment: Стало понятно. Всем спасибо огромное.